# Can I run do-release-upgrade to upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS but not the latest 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

my server runs 16.04 LTS and I have to upgrade to 18.04 LTS but not to 20.04 LTS because my Tableau Server doesn't support 20.04 LTS yet, only 18.04 LTS. How can I upgrade the server from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS? do-release-upgrade only updates to 20.04 LTS, there is no option to upgrade to an earlier LTS version.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` will *bump* you from the current release to the next release (ie. 16.04 to 16.10 if it was still supported; it's not so that path is gone) OR from a LTS to the next LTS (ie. 16.04 to 18.04).  It won't do more.  You'll need to reboot, then when you're ready (now or in the future), you can repeat the process to *bump* to the next release. Why do you think it wants to go to 20.04?   I would check your messages as that shouldn't happen, then your sources & what system you're actually on (`ubuntu-support-status` etc as your system may not be all *xenial*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to verify this please use the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade --check-dist-upgrade-only
```

You will know to which release your system will be upgraded

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, indeed do-release-upgrade just upgrades to the next LTS and doesn't skip them. --check-dist-upgrade-only shows it will upgrade to 18.04.5 LTS. Thanks for the help.